# NHibernate : How map datareader that return from ado.net query to class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ado.net

I have class which implement query ado.net concept by use connection from ISesssion Of NHibernate. I want map result that return form ado.net (such as DataTable or DataReader) to
class by apply classmap configuration.

please help for solution
thank you.

My Code

```
public class DbQuery : IDbQuery
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IDbDataParameter> _containerParameters;
    private readonly IDbSession _session;
    private IDbCommand _command;

    public DbQuery(IDbSession session)
    {
        _session = session;
        _containerParameters = new Dictionary<string, IDbDataParameter>();
    }

    public IDbDataParameter this[string parameterName]
    {
        get { return _containerParameters[parameterName]; }
    }

    public void CreateCommand(string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        _command = _session.CurrentSession.Connection.CreateCommand();
        _command.CommandText = commandText;
        _command.CommandType = commandType;
    }

    public void AddParameter(IDbDataParameter parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        _containerParameters[parameter.ParameterName] = parameter;
    }

    public void AddParameter(string parameterName, object value)
    {
        AddParameter(_session.CreateParameter(parameterName, value));
    }

    public void AddParameter(string parameterName, object value, ParameterDirection direction)
    {
        AddParameter(_session.CreateParameter(parameterName, value, direction));
    }

    public void AddParameter(string parameterName, object value, ParameterDirection direction, int size)
    {
        AddParameter(_session.CreateParameter(parameterName, value, direction, size));
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteDataTable()
    {
        var reader = ExecuteReader();
        var table = new DataTable("Data");
        table.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        table.Load(reader);

        return table;
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery()
    {
        var nonQuery = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ClearCommand();
        return nonQuery;
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar()
    {
        var scalar = _command.ExecuteScalar();

        ClearCommand();
        return scalar;
    }

    public DataRow ExecuteSingleRow()
    {
        var reader = _command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
        DataRow row = null;
        using (var table = new DataTable("Data"))
        {
            table.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            table.Load(reader);

            if (table != null && table.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                row = table.Rows[0];
            }
        }

        ClearCommand();
        return row;
    }

    public T ExecuteScalar<T>()
    {
        var scalar = ExecuteScalar();
        return (T)scalar;
    }

    public IDataReader ExecuteReader()
    {
        var reader = _command.ExecuteReader();

        ClearCommand();
        return reader;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void ClearCommand()
    {
        if (_command == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _command.Dispose();
        _command = null;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ClearCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ever figure this out?